# Степень корректности тире и запятых

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

*Попались на глаза предложения, в верности пунктуации которых мне очень хочется удостовериться.*

1. **Отдать выношенное и взращённое мной мировоззрение на растерзание переменам? — Легко.**

*Уместно ли написание тире после знака вопроса? Меня интересует конкретно данный вариант, то есть никакие перестройки текста предлагать не надо.*

2. **Изнемогая от тяжести дороги, издаю сокрушённые стенания — песнопение моего нутра.**

*Сомневаюсь в правильности постановки тире. Возможно, больше подойдёт запятая,
ведь имеется в виду, что сокрушённые стенания являются на самом деле песнопением нутра, значится, это что-то вроде поясняющего приложения (извините, точно не знаю), а ему, по сути, и запятой хватит.*

**Спасибо всем, кто ответит.**

Comment: Заголовок, конечно, заумнее не придумаешь.

Answer (score 3):

1. Можно записать так: ***Отдать выношенное и взращённое мной мировоззрение на растерзание переменам?  Легко!***

Я понимаю ваше желание обозначить паузу, но ставить тире здесь нельзя. Тире между предложениями используется при оформлении **прямой речи**, поэтому функция этого знака в данном случае  будет понята **неверно**.

Думаю, что сочетание вопросительного и восклицательного знаков в какой-то мере обозначат нужную интонацию.

2. ***Изнемогая от тяжести дороги, издаю сокрушённые стенания — песнопение моего нутра.***

Действительно, приложение имеет **пояснительный** характер, так как мы подбираем еще одно название для одного и того же предмета. Но именно поэтому нужно поставить **тире, а не запятую.**

При постановке запятой пояснительные отношения не будут выражены однозначно, так как мы можем их принять **за однородные,** как будто речь идет о разных предметах. В этом случае они будут прочитаны с перечислительной интонацией.